# Cisco controller ssh not taking in commands from python script

Tags: python, ssh, cisco

I am using a python script to connect to a local Cisco controller via ssh. I am using windows 10, python 3.7 and using the most recent paramiko library. I believe my script establishes a connection, but seems to not be able to properly enter a username and password.

```py
SSH code

import paramiko
import time
import getpass
import os
from host_file import network_devices
from config_file import host_conf


UN = input("Username : ")
PW = getpass.getpass("Password : ")


# For loop to specify number of hosts
for ip in  network_devices:
    print (ip)
    ssh1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh1.connect(ip, port=22, username=UN, password=PW)
    remote = ssh1.invoke_shell()
    remote.send('terminal length 0\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    #loop allows you to specify number of commands
    for command in host_conf:
        remote.send(' %s \n' % command)
        time.sleep(5)
        buf = remote.recv(65000)
        print (buf)
        f = open('sshlogfile0001.txt', 'ab')
        f.write(buf)
        f.close()
    ssh1.close()





Host file

network_devices = ['10.100.10.2','10.100.100.1']


config_file

host_conf = ['config paging disable','show time', 'exit']
```

These are the outputs the script prints back, They are from multiple run.

(Cisco Controller) 
User: terminal length 0
Password:***********
User: exit 
Password:

(Cisco Controller) 
User: terminal length 0
Password:***********
User: exit 
Password:

(Cisco Controller) 
User: terminal length 0
Password:***********
User: exit 
Password:

(Cisco Controller) 
User: terminal length 0
Password:***********
User: exit 
Password:

This is the output displayed on the cmd itself

b'\r\n\r\n(Cisco Controller) \r\nUser: terminal length 0\r\nPassword:***********\r\nUser:'
b' exit \r\nPassword:'
10.100.100.2
b'\r\n\r\n(Cisco Controller) \r\nUser: terminal length 0\r\nPassword:***********\r\nUser:'

Comment: Looks like the controller is prompting for the user/password pair on the interactive session rather than calling the pair passed during protocol negotiation sufficient. Might I suggest [`pxssh`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html) to make this easier?

Comment: is pxssh available for windows? Or is it just for linux?

Comment: Honestly couldn't tell you, but *if* it's POSIX-y platforms only (it's definitely not Linux-only), there are certainly other Expect analogs that'll work on Windows, including the TCL-based original. The whole point is to have a tool that's built for pattern matching on the remote output stream to look at what it's doing -- if it asks for a username, give it one; if it asks for a password, give it one; if it sends a prompt, send your next command, etc; that way you can get rid of horrid hacks like the hardcoded `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Another language may work, but I am attempting to sort the output data and grab certain information to then use in another command, I am not familiar enough with powershell or TCL to incorporate all these requirements into a single program I can give to my user. I figured python would be my best bet. After a quick google, python for windows can not use pxssh as it uses a pty.